# I have a water cooled ice machine

Tags: ice

The ice machine I purchase at a auction is water cooled. Can I separate the cooling water for the compressor and recirculate it through a tank of water so not wasting the compressor cooling water

Comment: Brand/model number? That would tell you a lot, and might just help us help you...

Comment: cold-ish tap water is cheaper than cooling room-temp water, at least in most places.

Comment: Depending on region, the tap water may be from glacial run-offs (great lakes) and those are quite cold even in the summer.